# multiple select queries using primary and foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have two tables `Sales` & `Country`. `Sales` has approx. 15 columns one of which is a primary key called `s_id`, `Country` has 5 columns and contains a foreign key also called `s_id`.

I want to write a query which will select only records in the Sales table where the s_id has more than one record in the Country table. Then from the list returned by this query perform another query which should return only rows where the field `usd_value > 0` or `eur_value > 0`. Both `usd_value` and `eur_value` are fields in the `Sales` table.

Below is a brief and simple example which hopefully helps.

```
 Sales 
 s_id       usd_value      eur_value
 MN13       0              5
 MN14       0              0
 MN15       325            125
 MN28       320            0

 Country
 s_id     country
 MN13     NL
 MN13     FR
 MN14     GB
 MN14     US
 MN15     US
 MN28     CA
 MN28     US
 MN28     MX


 Result I would like to see
 s_id     usd_value     eur_value
 MN13     0             5
 MN28     320           0
```

Comment: well I can't even get the first query to work at the moment, select deal_id
from MA_DEALS_COUNTRY
having count(deal_id) > 1

Comment: (select deal_id
from MA_DEALS_COUNTRY
group by deal_id
having count(deal_id) > 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
SELECT
    COUNT(c.[s_id]) Total,
    s.[usd_value],
    s.[eur_value]
FROM Sales s
LEFT JOIN Country c ON c.[s_id] = s.[s_id]
GROUP BY s.[s_id]
HAVING Total > 1
AND (usd_value > 0 OR eur_value > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select s.* 
from sales s
where 
(
 s.eur_value > 0
 or 
 s.usd_value > 0
)
and s.s_id
in
(
 select s_id
 from country
 group by s_id
 having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT S.* FROM
 Sales S JOIN 
       (
         SELECT s_id,Count(s_id) From Country Group By s_id Having Count(s_id) > 1
        ) R On S.s_id = R.s_id
Where S.usd_value > 0 Or S.eur_value >0
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd4d20/2)**

Output:

```
S_ID    USD_VALUE   EUR_VALUE
MN13    0           5
MN28    320         0
```